# Ansible handler is given a task to start a particular service. What will Ansible handler do if the service is already started when it is called?

Tags: ansible

**Ansible** handler is given a task to start a particular service. What will Ansible handler do if the service is already started when it is called?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what module and what definition you are using to restart the service. Typically (such with the `service` module) when a service is already started and you specify `state: started`, then **nothing** happens.

In handlers, you typically want to use `state: restarted`, which will make sure a service is restarted when the handler runs.